# vb.net windows application running on windows server 2008 R2 hangs when user paste text into textbox

Tags: vb.net, windows-server-2008-r2

The users connect to the server over RDP and are able to paste text ( emails etc) from their system to the application running on the server.

Over a period of time, when they switch back to RDP and **paste text into the application,** they are faced with the textbox turning black and the application hangs.

Several other VB.NET applications work on the same server without any problem. Also the application in question works without any issues directly on client machines.

Is this a memory issue? Should I clear the clipboard? Any light on this problem would be appreciated,thanks!

Comment: Is it a winforms application? Do you have access to the source code? Is it an unmodified winforms textbox with an unmodified pasting handler? Can you replicate the problem with a debugger attached? How long are offending Strings?

Comment: Yes, it is a winforms application and I do have access to the source code. Yes - Unmodified textbox and unmodified paste handler ! Am unable to replicate the problem with a debugger. The text pasted could be anywhere from 1 page to 10 pages of a word document.

Comment: Max lenght for textbox is set as : 2147483647

Comment: With or without a debugger can you create a repeatable test case to cause this error? How about replacing the text box with a button that calls a method that manually reads out the clipboard? Or for diagnostic reasons do something with threads and a timer that manually reads out the clipboard when

Comment: the Main thread hangs for too long.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Traubenfuchs ! I am thinking of creating a custom paste function and thread that, so the main thread does not make the application hang. Can't replicate the case but have seen this behavior on the client pc, when they login using rdp.

Comment: I have written down the way I do multithreading in winforms applications. Many people will be opposed to my ideas, but this way things simply work more the way I want them to... http://pastebin.com/dXYaaK1y I do not know the vb.net equivalents to the few code snippets I wrote down but they shouldn't be hard to find.